# How to change a model after creating a ModelViewset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API with django rest framework.
But I have a problem every time I want to modify a model when I have already created an associated ModelViewset.

For example, I have this model:

```py
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=150, unique=True)
    provider = models.CharField(_("provider"),max_length=150)
    build_date = models.DateField(_('build date'))
    category = models.ForeignKey("machine.CategoryMachine",
                                 related_name="machine_category",
                                 verbose_name=_('category'),
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE
                                )
    site = models.ForeignKey(
        "client.Site",
        verbose_name=_("site"),
        related_name="machine_site",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Machine")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Machines")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Fridge_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

And this viewset:

```py
class MachineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving machine.
    """
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
    serializer_class = MachineSerializer
    queryset = cache.get_or_set(
                        'machine_machines_list',
                        Machine.objects.all(),
                        60*60*24*7
                    )
    
    @swagger_auto_schema(responses={200: MachineSerializer})
    def list(self, request):
        serializer_context = {
            'request': request,
        }
        queryset = cache.get_or_set(
            'machine_machines_list',
            Machine.objects.all(),
            60*60*24*7
        )
        serializer = MachineSerializer(queryset, many=True, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @swagger_auto_schema(responses={404: 'data not found', 200: MachineSerializer})
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        serializer_context = {
            'request': request,
        }
        queryset = Machine.objects.all()
        machine = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = MachineSerializer(machine, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I want to add a field to my model, like for example a description. When I run the command `python manage.py makemigrations`
I get the error :
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column machine_machine.description does not exist`

I have to comment my viewset to be able to run the `makemigrations` and `migrate`.
How can I avoid having to comment each time the viewsets when I want to modify a model?

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: You will cache the results of a queryset for a week?? Are you _really_ sure about that? You might display stale data to users that way.

Comment: I delete the data from the cache when the result is changed (after adding an object for example...)

Answer (score 3):

In your view you have the following line in your class:

```
queryset = cache.get_or_set(
    'machine_machines_list',
    Machine.objects.all(),
    60*60*24*7
)
```

Since this line is present in the class declaration and not in a method of the class it is executed when the class is created / interpreted. This causes it to fire a query, since a queryset will need to be evaluated ([pickling Querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets) will force evaluation) to cache it. The problem here is that your models haven't been migrated yet and your queries fail. You can write that code in the `get_queryset` method by overriding it if you want:

```
class MachineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving machine.
    """
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
    serializer_class = MachineSerializer
    # Remove below lines
    # queryset = cache.get_or_set(
    #                     'machine_machines_list',
    #                     Machine.objects.all(),
    #                     60*60*24*7
    #                 )
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return cache.get_or_set(
            'machine_machines_list',
            Machine.objects.all(),
            60*60*24*7
        )
    ...
```

But this implementation is **critically** flawed! You are caching the queryset for a *week*. Lot's of new data can come in within that time period and you would be essentially serving *stale* data to your users. I would advise you to forego this sort of caching. Also you seem to be returning *all* the data from your view, consider some sort of filtering on this so that less memory is needed for such stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It works very well.

For the one week cache, I delete the keys as needed such as after adding a new machine. Knowing that there will be no more than 1 or 2 machines added/modified per month, the one week cache doesn't seem too bad.